# VB.NET LINQ Query Runtime Multi-Table Join

Tags: vb.net, linq, join, stringbuilder

I am using a StringBuilder to build a dynamic multi-table Join at runtime.

I need to move the Join statement outside of the LINQ Query use a variable in it's place.

```
Dim Results ' Object Type

Results = From tbl1DataRow In dtTable1.AsEnumerable()
          Group Join tbl2DataRow In dtTable2.AsEnumerable() On tbl1DataRow.Field(Of String)(2) Equals tbl2DataRow.Field(Of String)(2)
          Into g = Group
          Where g.Count = 0
          Select Case tbl1DataRow
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do?  Are you getting errors?  I don't know what `dt` and `myStringBuilderVariable` look like.  Are you having issues composing the query?  What does should it start like? Finish like?

Comment: I cannot hard code the Join statement which would follow the Group. I am constructing the Join statement outside of the LINQ Query. I end up with a String variable which I am trying to use in the LINQ Query. If I use the variable in place of a hard coded join statement, you will see the following error. "Range variable <variable> hides a variable in an enclosing block or a range variable previously defined in the query expression."

Comment: So you want to pass in keywords like `Where` and `Join` at runtime like you would using Dynamic SQL?  You can try using this [Dynamic LINQ library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library).  But also, this is pretty odd that you couldn't do this with hardcoded values.  If you can post more of our starting point and what you expect to accomplish, there might be a better way to structure the whole process.

Comment: I have updated the code above. I cannot hard code the Join as above. In some cases, I may construct muti-table joins and that must be done at runtime.